# Is there an AI algorithm that generates 2D vector graphics art like this image?

Tags: algorithms, artificial-intelligence

Is there an AI algorithm that generates 2D vector images with given examples like the the below images that is accessed on a website or something?[image]

Comment: Why should it be done by an AI algorithm?

Comment: @babou: by lazyness, possibly.

Comment: Alternatively, you can achieve this by means of HI (human intelligence): split the rocket design in basic shapes (body, nozzles, feet, portholes, tip...) and define assembly rules. Then select color schemes and components randomly. IMO, you will get faster to a satisfactory solution by following this path.